# Are multiple accounts at superuser.com allowed?

Tags: discussion

Are multiple accounts at superuser.com allowed?

When clicking on the symbol with the question mark I only found information on merging multiple accounts in one.

Comment: The tooltip of the "symbol with the question mark" is "Help Center and other resources". Clicking on this "symbol..." shows a list of options, usually, it's called a "dropdown menu" or just a "menu".

Answer (score 5):

#### Are multiple accounts at superuser.com allowed?

Yes, but.

> It is not a problem to have multiple accounts, as long as they aren't voting for each other and doing other sockpuppet-y things.
>
> Though it is generally discouraged, as what legitimate reason would you need for multiple accounts? Idle hands are the devil's playground, etc etc.

Source: [What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/267099) answer by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

> **When should sockpuppets be considered a problem?**
>
> There are a handful of legitimate reasons to maintain multiple accounts. A good rule of thumb for identifying abusive socks is: if
> the second account allows you to do something on the site that your
> normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse. Examples of
> this include (but are not limited to):
>
> - Voting on your own posts or comments
> - Answering your own questions with the other account(s)
> - Casting multiple votes on others' posts or comments
> - Supporting your own arguments ("+1: shog is right, don't know why the rest of you don't realize this")
> - Using bounties to circumvent the rep cap
> - Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc.
> - Violating site rules through another account to prevent sanctions from being applied to your main account

Source: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/267099) answer by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)

There are penalties for breaking the above rules.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned by [DavidPostill's answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/15006/1794161), people can have multiple accounts, but there are restrictions; users having multiple accounts should not use them to bypass the site algorithms, rules, policies and standards and voting fraud.

Some tips:

1. A person or group sharing the same computer should not vote for each other's posts.
2. Don't simulate discussions. If, for any reason, you use more than one account in the same question, don't reply, criticize, or endorse opinions between your accounts.
3. Before going into "innovative" / "creative" ways to use Super User features, get in touch with the *core community* (frequently active users, including community moderators) and wait to have enough feedback (you might have to be very patient).

Some measures are automatic; some depend on flags; some actions are irreversible.

Because of the above, I was looking for a *userscript* to help me to prevent accidental make interactions between my accounts. I found this [Don't let me interact with this user's posts (for sockpuppets, mostly)](https://stackapps.com/q/9039/105187).